# Svelte transition defined per transition and not per component

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-transition

I'm developing a Svelte UI with full page navigation using svelte-spa-router.
I'm facing the case where the UX designer defined the transition between page "per transition" and not per page has it's meant to be in Svelte (AFAIK).

[image]

E.g. in this UX page B1 out transition would :

- disappeared instantly when going back to the home page A ;
- slide left when going to C1 ;
- dissolve when going to B2.

The UX actually makes sense because B1/B2, C1/C2 are similar but treats the same subject from a different point of view.

Svelte transition are working great but are defined per component, with a `in` transition and an `out` transition.

I tried leveraging the fact that transition property could be object and reactive.

```
<script>
    import { fade } from "svelte/transition";
    let page = "A";
    let duration = 0;
    function goto(dest) {
        if(dest == "A" || page == "A") {
            duration = 0;
        } else {
            duration = 400;
        }
        page = dest;
    }
</script>

{#if page == "A"}
    <section class="A" transition:fade={{duration: duration}}>
        <h1>Page A</h1>
        <nav on:click={e => goto("B1")}>Goto B1</nav>
        <nav on:click={e => goto("B2")}>Goto B2</nav>
    </section>
{:else if page == "B1"}  
    <section class="B1" transition:fade={{duration: duration}}>
        <h1>Page B1</h1>
        <nav on:click={e => goto("A")}>Goto Back</nav>
        <nav on:click={e => goto("B2")}>Goto B2</nav>
    </section>
{:else if page == "B2"}
    <section class="B2" transition:fade={{duration: duration}}>
        <h1>Page B2</h1>
        <nav on:click={e => goto("A")}>Goto Back</nav>
        <nav on:click={e => goto("B1")}>Goto B1</nav>
    </section>
{/if}

<style>
    section {
        position: absolute;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }
    section.A {
        background: pink;
    }
    section.B1 {
        background: blue;
    }
    section.B2 {
        background: yellow;
    }
</style>
```

But I cannot figure out how to change the transition effect (maybe a custom transition function ?).
Moreover, this solution seems very complicated, time consuming and could really turn to a ball of spaghetti in a more complex UX.

In addition, in svelte-spa-router I did not found a way to know where I'm coming from (i.e. the prevision `location`) to manage the transition accordingly.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in:` syntax accepts javascript functions, things like `fade` are regular javascript functions this allows for switching.

```js
// pageTransion.js
function slidePage(el) {
  return fly(el, { x: 200, duration: 300 });
}
function disolvePage(el) {
  return fade(el, { duration: 300 });
}
let previous = "";
let current = "";
export function setNextPage(next) {
  previous = current;
  current = next;
}

export function pageTransition(el) {
  const transitions = {
    "b1-b2": disolvePage,
    "b1-c1": slidePage,
    // etc
  };
  return transitions[previous + "-" + current];
}


// b1.svelte
<div transition:pageTransition>
```

You'll need to call the `setNextPage` before activating the page.

svelte-spa-router doesn't expose the previous url, but you could listen to the onhashchange event and store the url history yourself.
( ordering is important, you can use the [capture phase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters) to run before the the spa-router code.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't know `transition` could be a function, that's great. I will check it out.